# SharedPreferences default values

Tags: android, preferences

I have a settings.xml file that contains Preferences for my app. All the values by default are set to "true" and its used by PreferenceActivity in my app.
In my main activity I read the values through

```
     SharedPreferences sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
     Boolean key = sp.getBoolean("M", false);
```

it gets me whatever I need at any run **except the first time**. Only when I open my app for the first time and doesn't open my settings menu I get "false". I mean I have to open menu and only after that the app run correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you move the values from settings.xml to the shared preferences without running PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because yor are getting the default value for first time. 
that is false -->

```
Boolean key = sp.getBoolean("M", false);
```

use this

```
Boolean key = sp.getBoolean("M", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp.getBoolean("M", true);` instead. Default values in preferences file is what it will be when preferences activity is first started. SharedPreferences know nothing about your settings.xml.

Alternatively you can have a separate defaults.xml file (or any other name) containing all the default values for all preferences. Then you use these values in both settings.xml (`@bool/default_M_value`) and your application (`sp.getBoolean("M", getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.default_M_value))`).

I personally would stick to first approach though.